# How to have offline CLHS available from the REPL?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, interactive-mode

I'm using GNU Common Lisp on Windows.

In interactive moed, after I type `(funcn`<kbd>TAB</kbd>, the REPL auto-completes the function name. When I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> again, the debugger triggers as follows:

```
Break 1 [31]> (isqrt

ISQRT is the symbol ISQRT, lies in #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP>, is accessible in 11
packages CLOS, COMMON-LISP, COMMON-LISP-USER, EXPORTING, EXT, FFI, POSIX,
READLINE, REGEXP, SCREEN, SYSTEM, names a
*** - CLHS-ROOT: variable *CLHS-ROOT-DEFAULT* has no value
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R2      Abort main loop
```

It looks like I can somehow integrate the reference (CLHS) with the interactive shell
 so that I can have it available quickly. Where can I find such an offline copy of CLHS and how to integrate it with the REPL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be downloaded from here: ftp://ftp.lispworks.com/pub/software_tools/reference/HyperSpec-7-0.tar.gz.

Then you should apparently put the location where you've unzipped it into the variable `*CLHS-ROOT-DEFAULT*` so that GCL can access it. (I myself use the HyperSpec from SLIME and therefore have its location in the Emacs variable `common-lisp-hyperspec-root`.)

Comment: Thanks! On top of that I discovered that there's no need to modify `*CLHS-ROOT-DEFAULT*` directly, as the function `clhs-root` (defined in `config.lisp` firstly checks the envvar `CLHSROOT` and also a registry key.

Answer (score 0):

See this post by Bill Clementson http://bc.tech.coop/blog/040411.html and the earlier one he'd linked to.